# Need to get URL HTTP request is being redirected to

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script to automate my Firewall login process. Here is what my Firewall do-
When I connect to my Wi-Fi and open google.com, it redirects to a URL like:

```
http://<IP>:<PORT>/fgtauth?<RAND-STRING>
```

It contains a basic username-password form, along with a hidden field 'magic' with value `<RAND-STRING>` of the URL. I have to submit this form with username and password to login to Firewall. I want to automate the process (and will schedule it to run every 4 hours to prevent auto-logout of Firewall).

Till now I have done this:

```
$url = "http://<IP>:<PORT>/fgtauth?04582fd55070345b"
$parameters = "4Tredir=http://google.com&magic=04582fd55070345b&username=<UN>&password=<PASS>"

$http_request = New-Object -ComObject Msxml2.XMLHTTP
$http_request.open('POST', $url, $false)
$http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 
  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
$http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", '$parameters.length')
$http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")
$http_request.send($parameters)
$http_request.statusText
```

which I copied from [here](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2010/04/29/sending-post-data-via-powershell.aspx). I have to open google.com manually from web browser, copy that 'magic' string from URL and paste it in script. If I do so, script runs fine and login is successful. I now have to somehow make request to google.com first, it'll get redirected to Firewall login page and extract that 'magic' string from it.

Please help me extracting that 'magic' string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would not suggest an answer that uses a different approach to the one in the question, however in this case my suggestion uses so little code I thought it may be appropriate.

The easiest way I know of to do this is using the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet. If the example url you provide is the actual format of the real url then you can do this:

```
$url = "https://www.theSiteThatWillRedirectYou.com"
$webResponse = Invoke-webRequest -uri $url
$absoluteUriFromResponse = $webResponse.BaseResponse.AbsoluteUri
$splitUri = $absoluteUriFromResponse.split("?")
$desiredString = $splitUri[1]
```

If the url is of the form ?parameter=value then you can do the following:

```
$url = "https://www.theSiteThatWillRedirectYou.com"
$webResponse = Invoke-webRequest -uri $url
$absoluteUriFromResponse = $webResponse.BaseResponse.AbsoluteUri
$splitUri = $absoluteUriFromResponse.split("?")
$desiredKeyValPair = $splitUri[1] | convertFrom-StringData
```

In this case if the url was, for example, whatever.com?rand=randValue then $desiredKeyValPair would contain:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                
rand                           randValue
```

Now these examples only work if there is only one parameter in the query string. If there are multiple parameters you would need to do a little extra work. For example if the url was like this: www.whatever.com?rand=randVal&otherParam=otherValue you would need to do something like this:

```
$splitOnQueryChar = $absoluteUriFromResponse.split("?")
$splitOnAmpersand = $splitOnQueryChar[1].split("&")
$keyValPairs = $splitOnAmpersand | convertFrom-StringData
```

At this point $keyValPairs would contain something like this:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                
rand                          randVal                                                                                                                                                                     
otherParam                       otherValue
```

These values can be referenced by name like this:

```
$keyValPairs.rand
```

*Included from comment:
I wasn't thinking in terms of the form on the page but Invoke-webrequest will capture forms/input fields etc, and these can usually be referenced by name.

Comment: Thank you very much! `$webResponse.BaseResponse.AbsoluteUri` was not working for me, don't know why. It was giving empty output. But, I picked the 'magic' value from Form using `$form=$webResponse.Forms[0]` and then `$form.Fields["magic"]`.

Comment: This answer has a mistake. It's $webResponse.BaseResponse.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri. Above is missing the 'ResponseUri' component.